# Is there a way of passing an argument directly to the wrapped logger (say, via kwargs)?

Tags: python, logging, structlog

I'm using `wrap_logger` to wrap a logger which makes use of e.g. `funcName`.

When using `log = wrap_logger(logger)`, `funcName` shows up as `_proxy_to_logger` instead of whatever function is making the log—so I'd like to ensure that `stacklevel=2` gets passed to the underlying logger (in fact, I'd like to ensure this is the case without having to explicitly pass it on every call, but maybe that's for another ticket).

If I do something like `log.info("This is a log", stacklevel=2)` then structlog interprets this argument as a key-value pair to add to the event dictionary.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't aware of stacklevel and have opened an issue: https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/537 It's impossible to answer your question tho without knowing your configuration – it's _probably_ possible to hack it somehow together.